# "You must set the minimum instance count to a value greater than or equal to the number of availability zones..." when updating Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following a tutorial to create an application in Elastic Beanstalk.  I created the application to be available in six availability zones.  Elastic Beanstalk created the application successfully and assigned it an auto scaling group with min/max/desired capacity of 1.

When I try to update the application with the Upload and Deploy button, I get the error `You must set the minimum instance count to a value greater than or equal to the number of availability zones or you will not have instances in each zone. For example if you select 'Any 2' you should set min=2.`

- If my application needs at least six instances because it is available in six availability zones, why did Elastic Beanstalk allow me to create and run my application with only one instance in the first place?
- Is there a way to update my application without changing my minimum capacity in my ASG to 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the application. I was able to do it by the following steps:

1. Open the Configuration of your Environment in the Elastic Beanstalk console.
2. Scroll to `Instance traffic and scaling` -> click 'Edit' to the right.
3. Scroll down to the 'Capacity' section -> 'Availability Zones'
4. Select `Any 1`
5. Under the 'Placement' dropdown select the desired AZ - I guess it's better to choose the one that is already holds your EC2 instance for this Environment.
6. Save and wait for update. Then you can try to upload a new version.